# how to write the regular expression that will accept numbers and ( ) / -

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I have the following function:

```
function IsInteger(str){
    return /^\d*[()-][0-9]*$/.test(str);
}
```

I wish `IsInteger()` function to return only numbers and some special charaters i.e. `"(, ), /, -"`

Comment: Your RE says: "any number of digits, then one of `[]-`, then any number of digits"; it is a good way to say "digits and exactly one of `[]-` somewhere inside. If you want to freely mix digits and "special characters", `/^[0-9()-/]*$/` would be better.

Comment: Dear @Amadan thanks for the suggestion! :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get only numbers and one of the the special characters from list `"(, ), /, -"` this is the regex that you are looking for:

```
/^[\d\(\)\/\-]+$/
```

> `\d` match a digit [0-9]
>
> `\(` matches the character ( literally
>
> `\)` matches the character ) literally
>
> `\/` matches the character / literally
>
> `\-` matches the character - literally

Your function will be like this:

```js
    function IsInteger(str) {
      return /^[\d\(\)\/\-]+$/.test(str);
    }

    alert(IsInteger("/88868)(11)-22"));
```

You can check **[the DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/nO0eQ2/1)** here.

Comment: @SajidKhan please accept the answer if it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use pipe character, as an example \d|()|\,|-

[**Example**](http://regexr.com/3bgfp)